# Unique constraint check fails too late with Spring Boot Starter Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, h2, unique-constraint

I'm quite surprised about the unique constraint feature. I'm developping a spring boot app with H2 database for unit test.

One of my entity has a unique constraint.
Below the headers of the class User.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "identifier" }) })
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_pkey", sequenceName = "user_id_seq")
```

I have written a small unit test to check the unique constraint.

> Before test function

```
@Before
public void before() {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setBlackListed(false);
        user1.setIdentifier("test@tby.com");
        user1.setRefreshToken("azerty");          
        this.userDao.save(user1);
}
```

> My test

```
@Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void user_identifierUnicityTest() {
    User user4 = new User();
    user4.setBlackListed(false);
    user4.setIdentifier("test@tby.com");
    user4.setRefreshToken("azerty4");
    User response = this.userDao.save(user4);
    this.userDao.findByIdentifier("test@tby.com");
}
```

I'm quite surpised, i was thinking that the exception would be thrown during the save request. Or the exception is thrown during the find request.

The constraint integrity is check during a select request and not an insert. I do not understand the result.

Is it the normal behavior of unique constraint ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unique constraint is maintained by the database. This will cause an `insert` to fail would it violate the constraint. Hibernate will not write entities to the database until it has to, and when this happens it is called [flushing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing). When you issue a search query, the default behaviour for Hibernate is to flush before querying so that any changes made to the persistent context is visible when querying.

So your changes is inserted into the database as a side effect of executing a query. This will cause the failure at this point, which could be perceived as later than expected...

Comment: You’re welcome! Happy coding with hibernate, it’s an amazing framework!

Comment: Soory, I know this question is old, but i'am encoutering the exact same problem, and i'm wondering what is the solution to prevent hibernate to persist the data if it's already existing in the database. Whe should do a manual chack, or a custom validator maybe ?

Comment: @AlainDuguine It depends on a lot of things... Create a new question with more details of your use case and your code!

Comment: Thanks ! I found my answer by making a repository.flush() in my service layer.